# Running the same command on several ssh servers using tmux

Tags: linux, ssh, tmux

Is is it possible to type a command once and run it over several servers connected via ssh using tmux?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for might be "synchronize-panes". With this option turned on, every keystroke is deliver to every pane of current window. Therefore, you can achieve your goal by:

1. Split a tmux window into multiple panes and ssh to different servers in each panes
2. turn on the aforementioned option. i.e.

   tmux set-window-option synchronize-panes
3. type whatever command you intended.

In fact, I bond that option to Prefix + C-s in my tmux.conf:

```
bind-key C-s set-window-option synchronize-panes
```